# poles and algebraic power series

Tags: complex-analysis, field-theory

Let $f(z)=\sum_{n\ge0}a_nz^n$ be a power series defined on a open subset $\mathcal U$ of $\mathbb C$. I want to prove that if $f$ is algebraic over $\mathbb C(z)$, that is there exists non all zero polynomials $P_0,\cdots,P_s$ of $\mathbb C[z]$ such that for every $z\in\mathcal U$, $\sum_{i=0}^sP_i(z)f^i(z)=0$, then $f$ admits only finitely many poles and zeros.

But I did not manage to prove that. Any answer will be welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a reason to think it is true? What did you try?

Comment: $f(z)=0$ requires $P_0(z)=0$. That's the whole proof.

Comment: actually even more is true, namely that $f$ extends to a multivalued analytic function with finitely many singularities in the (extended) plane, so in particular one can construct single-valued branches by cutting out appropriate arcs and of course same is true for $1/f$ since that is obviously algebraic; this follows for example from the fact that $f$ satisfies a homogeneous linear ODE (of degree at most $s$)  with polynomial coefficients and for those it is easily shown the above -